# integral inequality involving Beta function limits..

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals, beta-function

hope this question is not too silly. Does the following inequality hold??

\begin{equation}
\int_{l}^{w} \frac{t^{a-1}dt}{(1+ut)^{p+1}} \le  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{a-1}dt}{(1+ut)^{p+1}} = \frac{1}{u^a}B(a,p+1-a)
\end{equation}

where $0 < l < w < \infty$ and $0<a$, $1<p$.

Common sense says yes...because of the integration limits ... $[0,\infty)$ sweeps a greater area... but in mathematics, common sense is usually misleading...thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since the integrand is real, and strictly positive almost everywhere, the integral is not increased (indeed, decreased) by shrinking the interval of integration.

If you want to get really technical, take the integrand as a measure $d\mu$ and use that $A \subset B \implies \mu(A) \leq \mu(B)$ for $\mu$-measurable sets $A$ and $B$. Intervals are $\mu$-measurable since they are Borel sets and the measure is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, etc...

Comment: Many thanks  Chappers... just one more question.... Would this inequality hold for negative exponents (a < -1 , p < -1)??..I am wondering about the  analytic continuation of the Beta function ...Thanks

Comment: No: since in either of those cases the integral diverges, one can make the left-hand side as large as required by taking $l$ sufficiently small (or $m$ sufficiently large, depending on the case in question), while the Beta-function continues to remain finite (and possibly is even negative anyway!).